# is "relationship" = "grammatical relationship" in linguistics articles?

Tags: terminology

for example in the [Morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_(linguistics)) article of wikipedia

> In linguistics, morphology (/mɔːrˈfɒlədʒi/) is the study of words,
>   how they are formed, and their *relationship* to other words in the same
>   language

Answer (score 3):

No, not in general. "Relationship" could also mean, e.g., "semantic relationship", "phonological relationship", "genealogical relationship", ...
Depends on context, usually it is clear from the scope of the article what kind of relationship is meant, but there certainly are many more kinds of relationships in linguistics apart from "grammatical" (which is already a very broad term).
In the particular example, the given wording is rather vague, but it most probably does refer to some kind of grammatical (morpho-syntactic) relationship.

Comment: There are indeed lots of relationships -- and kinds of relationships -- between words, but that's a rather useless definition of morphology to start with. [This is what I used to tell my classes](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/3486/482), as a mnemonic, with details of varieties of morphology [(inflectional versus derivational morphology, for instance) here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) .